# AngularJS : Why is my ng-change not logging the actual model item, but instead the binding text?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-ng-change

[image]

My model is the array `vh.loadedViews` with 4 items.

My ng-repeat on the option: `ng-repeat="view in vh.loadedViews"`

my ng-model on the select: `ng-model="view.description"`

However in my ng-change function `vh.chooseView` it's printing out the binding text and not the actual model data.

**Markup:**

```
<section class="saved-views-modal" ng-show="vh.loadSavedModal">
    <header><h1>Select a saved view</h1></header>

    <select name="select"
            ng-model="view.description"
            ng-change="vh.chooseView(view.description)">

        <option ng-repeat="view in vh.loadedViews"
                value="view.description">{{view.description}}</option>
    </select>

    <button class="btn-green"
            ng-click="vh.loadSavedView(view.description)">
                Load View
    </button>
</section>
```

**Directive Controller:**

```
var vm = this; // vh in markup

vm.chooseView = function(description) {
    console.log('chooseView > view.description: ');
    console.log(description);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `ngOptions` and not an `ngRepeat` on an `option` element!!!!!!!!

Comment: Is there a good example you know off? Or would use in this case?

Comment: `ng-options = "view as view.description for view in vh.loadedViews`, and your `ngChange` - pass in `view` as the param to get the entire object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not populated `value` tag of your options. You should populate it using   interpolation like `value="{{view.description}}"` to render option value.

Also you ng-model should be `ng-model="vh.description"` instead of `view.description`

**Markup**

```
<select name="select"
        ng-model="vh.description"
        ng-change="vh.chooseView(view.description)">

    <option ng-repeat="view in vh.loadedViews"
            value="{{view.description}}">{{view.description}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Sweet! This works :D another quick question, how would you set a default `selected` option?

Comment: @LeonGaban I'd do use `ng-init` in this case like `ng-init="vh.description=vh.loadedViews[0].description"` that will set first object description